# Change the transformz property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to change the transformz of an element using jquery. I have a div with css:

```
.bottom_face {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(487px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(347px);
 }
```

When the user changes a property on a form I would like to change the translateZ value to add the amount they enter:

```
$('.bottom_face ').css('-webkit-transform') ??
```

How do I access the translateZ property of the above *without overwriting the rotateX and rotate properties*?

Thanks

Comment: with jQuery you don't have to define the `-webkit-` prefix

Answer (score 1):

Op,

Firstly, [I set up a Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/aLyMV2?p=preview) that achieves what you ask. Here's how I did it:

### JS

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#amount_to_rotate').keydown(function () {
        var el = $(".bottom_face"),
            amt = parseInt($(this).val());
        rotZ = {
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateX(-9deg) rotate(-10deg) translateZ(' + amt + 'px)',
            '-moz-transform'   : 'rotateX(-9deg) rotate(-10deg) translateZ(' + amt + 'px)',
        }
        el.css(rotZ);
    }).keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            // Return to state given by CSS class
            $(".bottom_face").attr('style', ' ');
        }
    });
});
```

### Details

The `input` has a `keydown` and `keyup` event listener. When the users enters a value, it's added to an object, then pushed to the element's `style` attribute via jQuery's `css` function. Using an object in this way allows us to set static values and pass a variable—in this case `amt`— for the `translateZ` value.

To be safe, since we're dealing with user input, we santize the `val()` of the input by pulling out only numbers: `parseInt($(this).val());`

Also worth noting, I had to modify the values you originally specified for the transforms as `rotateX(-90deg)` flips the element on its x-axis in such a way that it becomes invisible. If that is your desired outcome, you can obviously change that back to whatever you see fit.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that I tried to strip down to the bare minimum:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    var z = $("#z").val();
    $(".bottom-face").each(function() {
        var $c = $(this);
        var css;
        if (css = $c.css("-webkit-transform")) {    // assignment
            $c.css("-webkit-transform",
               $c.css("-webkit-transform") + " translateZ(" + z + "px)"
            );
            //console.log( $c.css("-webkit-transform") );
        }
    });
});
```

And the [**link to jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/afwRt/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just append the changed translateZ?

```
.bottom_face {
    transform: translateZ(487px);
}
```

results in the same as

```
.bottom_face {
    transform: translateZ(487px) translateZ(-50px) translateZ(50px);
}
```

**EDIT**: [Example of what I mean.](http://jsfiddle.net/GxbNV/1/)

Comment: I need to do this client side dynamically to change the css

Comment: I don't think I understand where the problem is. Added an example to illustrate what I think of (with rotate instead of translateZ, but that doesn't change anything)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.css(-webkit-transform)` it will return a [`matrix3d`](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/Functions.html) value, which makes it very difficult to find the original values.

Example of `matrix3d`:

```
matrix3d(-1, 0.00000000000000012095693648649962, -0.000000000000000019157696688784726, 0, -0.00000000000000012246467991473532, -0.9876883405951378, 0.15643446504023087, 0, 0, 0.15643446504023087, 0.9876883405951378, 0, 0, 76.18358447459244, 481.0042218698321, 1)
```

You can find the `rotate` value: [source](http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/) or [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/459jS/112/); unfortunately, this does not include `rotateX` or `rotateY`.

Easiest way to go about this would be to do something like this:

```
var _translate = '30px';
$('.bottom_face').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(' + _translate + ')');
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/SLGdE/21/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Heres a javascript solution:

**1. convert transformation property of object to a string**

```
var currentTransformation = String(myobject.style.transform);
```

**2. replace the the value that you want transformed**

```
var finalTransformation = currentTransformation.replace("translateZ(100px)", "translateZ(YOURVALUEpx)");
```

**3. assign new transformation**

```
myobject.style.transform = finalTransformation;
```

Done!